# create apache virtual host

Tags: apache2, puppet, virtualhost

I have to create api.conf in /etc/apache2/sites-available dir in a server(xyz02.software.com). The apache config is managed via apache module(apache::vhost) in role::script..so basically it is ///modules/role/manifest/script.pp......

<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

ServerName xyz02.software.com

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/api-error.log

CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/api-access.log combined

---

apache::vhost { 'xyz02.software.com':

ensure  => present,

port    => 80,

docroot => /var/www,

serveradmin => webmaster@localhost,

servername  => xyz02.software.com,

notify      => [ Service['apache2'], ],
}

when i write this in puppet this way, it create with name 25-xyz.software.com.conf while i have to get with name api.conf....I don't know how i should mention to get with api.conf name.....also this script create the file also in other servers like xyz01 and xyz03 which also shouldn't happen....Is their anything like if statement I should provide?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but fundamentally the `apache` module assumes it has complete control over the Apache config files, their names and locations. This means that you can't tell `apache::vhost` to use `api.conf`.

The Puppet manifest for `apache::vhost` is hardcoded to use filenames of the form `25-vhostname.conf`:

https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-apache/blob/main/manifests/vhost.pp#L2205

The good news is that this almost certainly doesn't matter. The way Apache config works, `api.conf` and the Puppet vhost config will most likely play together nicely.

Comment: I used this way and it wrked for me but it didn't add the file in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/   dir ..what is missing?                                                                                  
 file { '/etc/apache2/sites-available/api.conf':
         ensure => present,
         owner  => root,
         group  => root,
         mode   => '0644',
         links  => follow,
         source => 'puppet:///modules/server/api.conf',
         notify => [Exec["enable api.conf"],],                                                                                         }